# Combine three nginx rewrites into one

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, nginx

Is it possible to rewrite this regular expression so it fits all my use-cases below?

```
        location ~ \.mp3$ {
            rewrite "^/(\d{4})/0(\d)/0(\d)/(.*).mp3$" /$1/$2/$3/$4.mp3 permanent;
            rewrite "^/(\d{4})/0(\d)/(\d{1,2})/(.*).mp3$" /$1/$2/$3/$4.mp3 permanent;
            rewrite "^/(\d{4})/(\d{1,2})/0(\d)/(.*).mp3$" /$1/$2/$3/$4.mp3 permanent;
        }
```

Real URL: `2012/7/8/piper.mp3`

Should match:

```
  2012/7/8/piper.mp3
  2012/07/8/piper.mp3
  2012/7/08/piper.mp3
  2012/07/08/piper.mp3
```

Thanks

Comment: You can try: `rewrite "^/(\d{4})/0?(\d{1,2})/0?(\d{1,2})/(.*).mp3$" /$1/$2/$3/$4.mp3 permanent;`

Comment: That will cause an infinite loop of redirects, since it will also catch `2012/7/8/piper.mp3` and try to redirect it to `2012/7/8/piper.mp3`.

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about `nginx`. Had it been mod_rewrite I could have suggested to have `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /0` to avoid looping.

Comment: Ok, forget about the rewrite combination, what are we really trying to do, remove the 0's from the month and day?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I'm trying to do.